# Delphi code compilation error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

[image]

when i compile my code i can see that some lines are not compiled. Due to this issue some codes does not execute according to the way i want.
i have attached a screenshot of the delphi IDE in the debug mode. Blue dots on the left shows the lines which are compiled and those lines without the blue dots does not function properly or not complied
As can see on the watch window that variable dPcnt value is 0 taxP, srvP, serv_charge does not have a proper value but in the code window can see that the variables have been initialized to 0
Can someone help me out to correct the issue.

Comment: Almost certainly the bug is in your code. The compiler is entitled to optimise out code that has no observable impact. Sometimes the blue dots are drawn incorrectly by the IDE. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates a compiler error. I am prepared to bet that you cannot do that, and that your attempts to do so will simply reveal that it is your code that is defective.

Comment: You should also enable compiler warnings. You will find your code is full of them.

Comment: And to be clear about what I mean by code with no impact, much of your code is like this, `a := 0; a := something;` and the compiler recognises the pointlessness of the first assignment. And will warn you about it. So, almost surely your code is wrong, the compiler is right, and there's no question her until you make a [mcve].

Comment: Do not post images of your code. Copy and paste the code itself into your question.See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for the reasons why you should not post images.

Answer (score 2):

It is the optimizer that has removed useless lines like

```
srvP := 0;
```

because you don't use that value before you assign a new value on line 770.

I can not see how and where the other variables are used, but I bet the reason is similar.

You can turn optimization on and off with the compiler directive `{$O+} or {$O-} {$OPTIMIZATION ON} or {$OPTIMIZATION OFF}`. But, please note what help says about it:

> Other than for certain debugging situations, you should never have a
>   need to turn optimizations off. All optimizations performed by the
>   Delphi compiler are guaranteed not to alter the meaning of a program.
>   In other words, the compiler performs no "unsafe" optimizations that
>   require special awareness by the programmer.

If you have compiler hints turned on (`{$HINTS ON}`) you will see hints in the form `H2077 Value assigned to '%s' never used` for lines that are 'useless'.
Further info here:

[H2077 Value assigned to '%s' never used #Delphi#](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/H2077_Value_assigned_to_%27%25s%27_never_used_(Delphi))